# Efficient way to exchange file contents

Tags: c++, c, file, file-descriptor

I have N files. File0, File1...File(n-1). My program always generate logs on these files. I always write to File0. If File0 exceeds the predefined size then File1 passes it contents to File2 and and File2 to File3...to File(n-1) and after that File0 passes its content to File1. So basically logs are sorted by modification date from File0 to File(n-1). My problem is how to pass these file contents efficiently. Each file size maybe 100MBs. So I just can't deep copy them.

**My approach**

I will destroy file(n-1). Then rename file (n-2) to file(n-1) and rename File(n-3) to File(n-2) and so on to File0 renamed to File1. Then I will create File0 again and write on it.

**My question** is can I just somehow exchange file pointers or fds so that all these complexity with renaming and destroying is not needed? Or is there any other simpler/efficient way to do the exchange.

Comment: Why do this the hard way?  Can't fileN be the newest log and fileN-1 works back in the history to file0?  This is a lot easier to implement and saves a lot of copying/renaming/shuffling things around.

Comment: think of a better indexing scheme. You dont have to rename any file if you just keep track of which one is the one that is currently written to

Comment: @NathanOliver, stil I will have to pass the contents from FileN to FileN-1 and N-1 to N-2 and so on right? And that needs renaming.

Comment: @Tahlil: No. When you create a new log file, you just increment N by 1.

Comment: Why?  You fill file0, then you move on to file1.  Once you fill that you move to file2.  You just keep going up when you fill a log file.  This makes 0 the oldest and N the current.

Comment: But my N is a fixed predefined number. I can't increment that. I predefine the number of log files.

Comment: So you only get N files and you have to store a rolling log?

Comment: If you insist on your technique, then you're stuck with a bunch of rename operations.  If you create the new files, so file 0 is the oldest and file N is the newest, then you have no renaming to do.  I'd avoid the renaming.

Comment: @nathanOliver Yes. But the rolling log will not work because I must have a predefined file number on which I will write the latest log. In my case its always File0. jonathanLeffer, This way I will have so much log that I will run out of memory eventually.

Comment: Then when you create a new log, delete the oldest one.

Comment: You don't need to delete the last log file, just truncate it and rename it while you rename all the other files. Then rename it to `file0`

Comment: Do you have to have file0 be the newest file?

Comment: Its best if its 0 or N so that it will have an order.

Comment: Why don't you use a program like `logrotate`?

Comment: @Barmar I think it doesn't have support for all platforms.

Comment: It looks like many of the above commenters did not read your problem correctly.  Your rename solution seems fine; I see no reason to change it.  It is essentially what logrotate does.

Comment: Seconded on using logrotate.  Don't reinvent the wheel when other programs do it so well.

Comment: @stark, Yes I have ended up implementing that. Taywee, _logrotate_ doesn't have support for all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

> **My question** is can I just somehow exchange file pointers or fds so that all these complexity with renaming and destroying is not needed? Or is there any other simpler/efficient way to do the exchange.

The short answer (although not encompassing) is: No, this wouldn't be effective.

The longer answer is: depending on what you want.

- Do you want file0 to constantly remain full and "flow-over" into file1?

  If this is the case, then you need to keep all the files open, keeping the file descriptors static so you can control overflow, probably implementing a recursive log `write` function (IMHO... not fun).

  If this is your intention, then yes, you can definitely juggle the file descriptors, but you'll get a heavy performance hit anytime you write to a log file.
- Do you want file0 to "become" file1 once it's full, like pushing data to a LIFO stack of files, so you start fresh with an empty file0?

  If this is the case, since data isn't "flowing" between the files, there is no point in keeping all the files open and wasting system resources. You'll only handle the files when rotation occurs.

  You will probably also need to implement a custom `write` function that locks and synchronizes write operations, so no race conditions occur while file rotation is in effect.

Good luck!